# I want to drag a column value which are in integer with respect to another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, ffill

Below is my data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','bbb','ddd','eee','eee','fff'],
                'c1':[35,'NA','NA','NA',4,'NA','NA','NA',56,406],
                'c2':[35,'NA','NA','NA',43,'NA','NA','NA',67,77],
                'c3':[36,'NA','NA','NA',104,'NA','NA','NA',44,306]})
```

I want to drag integer values of 'c1' 'c2', and 'c3' with respect to column 'vin'.

Below is the expected output:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vin':['aaa','aaa','aaa','bbb','bbb','bbb','ddd','eee','eee','fff'],
                'c1':[35,35,35,4,4,4,'NA',56,56,406],
                'c2':[35,35,35,43,43,43,'NA',67,67,77],
                'c3':[36,36,36,104,104,104,'NA',44,44,306]})
```

**Note:** The value of 'vin' column  'ddd' will remain as 'NA' as there is no integer value is available for 'ddd'.

I tried ffill() or groupbyffill() but I don't get the expected output.
Below are lines of code, I tried.

```
#(1)
df['c1'] = df.groupby(['vin'])['c1'].ffill()


#(2)
df[["c1","c2" "c3"]] = df[["c1", "c2","c3"]].fillna(df.groupby(['vin'])[["c1", "c2","c3"]].ffill())


#(3)
df["c1"] = df.groupby('vin')['c1'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one non missing value per group with `ffill` first sorting clumns:

```
c = ["c1","c2", "c3"]
df[c] = df.replace('NA',np.nan).sort_values(['vin', 'c1']).groupby('vin')[c].ffill()
print (df)
   vin     c1    c2     c3
0  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
1  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
2  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
3  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
4  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
5  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
6  ddd    NaN   NaN    NaN
7  eee   56.0  67.0   44.0
8  eee   56.0  67.0   44.0
9  fff  406.0  77.0  306.0
```

Or aggregate first non missing values for new columns in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
c = ["c1","c2", "c3"]
df[c] = df.replace('NA',np.nan).groupby('vin')[c].transform('first')
print (df)
   vin     c1    c2     c3
0  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
1  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
2  aaa   35.0  35.0   36.0
3  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
4  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
5  bbb    4.0  43.0  104.0
6  ddd    NaN   NaN    NaN
7  eee   56.0  67.0   44.0
8  eee   56.0  67.0   44.0
9  fff  406.0  77.0  306.0
```